# moving current file open in dialog to directory

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

Here i Open a file but i wont it to open and then be moved to folder in another directory were the program is heres the code i got so far

```
 Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Please Select a File"

    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:temp"

    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

End Sub

Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk

    Dim strm As System.IO.Stream

    strm = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()

    TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()

    If Not (strm Is Nothing) Then

        'insert code to read the file data

        strm.Close()

        MessageBox.Show("File Opened")

    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Have you looked at the `System.IO.File` class?

Answer (score 0):

First off... This isn't even a directory.

```
"C:temp"
```

If you want the initial directory of the OpenFileDialog1 control to be in the same directory where your application is located...Try this...

```
OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath
```